# How to set z-index of a plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a page where a plugin seems to be overriding the z-index of my dropdown menu element in mobile. The dropdown is set to `z-index: 100;` and it works for all other pages, but on the one page I have a plugin, the plugin shows over the menu when it's dropped. Either the plugin z-index is set to 100, or it's overriding z-index of the dropdown menu.

So i found the plugin ID and targeted it, didn't work.

```
#wpcf7-f337-p187-o1 {z-index: 98;}
```

First I targeted container element, didn't work, then container element followed by class, didn't work, then specificity like so:

```
.entry-content>.wpcf7{z-index: 98;}
```

Didn't work

So I set the body in that page to z-index 98, didn't work.

```
body.page-id-187{z-index: 98;}
```

Didn't work.

Both `.dropdown-menu` and the container `.collapse` are set to z-index 100, background-color: white like so:

```
@media(max-width: 768px){ul.dropdown-menu li a{position: relative; left: 55px; text-align: unset; font-size: 38px !important; background-color: white; color: black !important; line-height: 30px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: unset !important; margin-left: unset !important;z-index: 100;}}
```

And so:

```
@media(max-width: 768px){.collapse {position: absolute; height: 775px; background-color:white; z-index: 100; top:75px; left: -50px; line-height: 10px;}}
```

Html

```
<div class="entry-
content"><div role="form" 
class=
"wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f337- 
p187-o1" lang="en-US" 
dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader- 
response"></div>
<form 
action="/contact/#wpcf7- 
f337-p187-o1" method="post" 
class="wpcf7-form" 
novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: 
none;">
<input type="hidden" 
name="_wpcf7" value="337" 
/>
<input type="hidden" 
name="_wpcf7_version" 
value="5.1.3" />
<input type="hidden"  
name="_wpcf7_locale" 
value="en_US" />
<input type="hidden" 
name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" 
value="wpcf7-f337-p187-o1" 
/>
<input type="hidden" 
name="_wpcf7_container
_post" value="187" />
</div>
<p><label>NAME<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form- 
control-wrap your-name">. 
<input type="text" 
name="your-name" value="" 
size="40" class="wpcf7- 
form-control wpcf7-text 
wpcf7-validates-as- 
required" aria- 
required="true" aria- 
invalid="false" /></span> 
</label></p>
<p><label>EMAIL<br />
```

Mobile page [here](https://4309.co.uk/contact)

Comment: Please consider creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or other available tools like [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codpen.io](https://codpen.io) for us.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the z-index to an incredible high value, like `z-index: 999999 !important;` Maybe the plugin has not an as high index.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer? So users with similar problems can easily see that is has been solved and how that was achieved. Thank you very much! Happy it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element with the higher z-index will be displayed above. To make sure your element is on top, you can set an huge z-index value, which definately is higher than the one of the plugin element:

```
z-index: 999999 !important;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

"An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order."